# c circular double linked-list: traverses fwd/rev for end node gives different pointer address

Tags: c, iterator, doubly-linked-list

related post: [c circular double linked-list delete_node - iterate traverses deleted node on first pass after delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22576064/c-circular-double-linked-list-delete-node-iterate-traverses-deleted-node-on-fi)

All, implementing a search for node contianing line number 'x' prior to deleting that node, I ran across a problem where both forward and reverse searches identify the proper node, but the pointer for the caller's node address is reported differently by the reverse search than for the forward? This applies to the last node (hightest line number) only. If only the forwrd search is used (pba_fwd_iter_test), then the last node is deleted properly. However, if the reverse search is used (pba_rev_iter_test), then the address set by "(victim->next)->prev = victim->prev;" is incorrect, it sets "(victim->next)->prev = (victim->next)->prev". For example, arriving at the end node with a reverse search and then preforming the delete_node results in the following:

```
49: 7 - (line to delete) This is a line of text that is somewhere around 50 to 80 characters in length

48 - prev: 0x604a80  cur: 0x604b10  next: 0x604ba0
49 - prev: 0x604b10  cur: 0x604ba0  next: 0x603010  <-- delete_node
 0 - prev: 0x604ba0  cur: 0x603010  next: 0x6030a0

48 - prev: 0x604a80  cur: 0x604b10  next: 0x603010
49 - prev: 0x604b10  cur: 0x604ba0  next: 0x603010  <-- (node deleted)
 0 - prev: 0x603010  cur: 0x603010  next: 0x6030a0
              \_______________\______ Error (should be prev: 0x604b10)
```

@WhosCraig graciously helped with the delete_node function which works fine, but I cannot figure out why when locating the same node with the reverse search results in the delete_node failing to set "(victim->next)->prev = victim->prev;" properly. As a test of the reverse search, I simply stepped one additional node toward the beginning and then went forward one node back to the node in question and then the delete_node worked fine. (simply an additional: list = &(*list)->prev; list = &(*list)->next;. So the issue has something to do with the pointer state when arriving at the end-node with a reverse search rather than a forward seach -- that is what I need help figuring out. Here is the output of the pointer addresses following both forward and reverse searchs, as well as following the quick ->prev ->next:

```
=========== pba_fwd_iter_test() ===========
passing list = &(*list)->next to tstpptr (0x605b28)
tstpptr(): list     : 0x605b28
tstpptr(): &list    : 0x7ffff14633a8
tstpptr(): *list    : 0x605ba0
tstpptr(): &(*list) : 0x605b28  <- caller's address reported
tstpptr(): &(**list): 0x605ba0     with forward search

tstpptr(): &(*list)->next : 0x605bb8

=========== pba_rev_iter_test() ===========
passing list = &(*list)->next to tstpptr (0x604020)
tstpptr(): list     : 0x604020
tstpptr(): &list    : 0x7ffff14633a8
tstpptr(): *list    : 0x605ba0
tstpptr(): &(*list) : 0x604020  <- caller's address reported
tstpptr(): &(**list): 0x605ba0     with reverse search

tstpptr(): &(*list)->next : 0x605bb8

passing list = &(*list)->next to tstpptr (0x605b28)
tstpptr(): list     : 0x605b28
tstpptr(): &list    : 0x7ffff14633a8
tstpptr(): *list    : 0x605ba0
tstpptr(): &(*list) : 0x605b28  <- caller's address reported after
tstpptr(): &(**list): 0x605ba0     &(*list)->prev; &(*list)->next

tstpptr(): &(*list)->next : 0x605bb8
```

The following are the relevant code snippets with the link to the full source at the beginning. Thank you for any help you can provide:

```
/*
full source: http://www.3111skyline.com/dl/dev/prg/src/ll-double-cir-1.c.txt
*/

struct record
{
char *line;
int lineno;
int linetype;
struct record *prev;
struct record *next;
};
typedef struct record rec;

void  // traverse in fwd direction to find hightest line no.
pba_fwd_iter_test (rec **list, int num);
void  // traverse in rev direction to find hightest line no.
pba_rev_iter_test (rec **list, int num);
void  // dump the pointers for examination
tstpptr (rec **list);

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
// <snip> fill struct with 50 records for testing (lineno '0' based 0-49)
pba_fwd_iter_test (&textfile, 49);
pba_rev_iter_test (&textfile, 49);
return 0;
}

void
pba_fwd_iter_test (rec **list, int num) {
printf ("=========== %s() ===========\n",__func__);
int linemax = getmaxline (*list);
int iterno = 0;
while (((*list)->lineno != num) && (iterno <= linemax)) {
    iterno++;
    list = &(*list)->next;
}
printf ("passing list = &(*list)->next to tstpptr (%p)\n", list);
tstpptr (list);
}

void
pba_rev_iter_test (rec **list, int num) {
printf ("=========== %s() ===========\n",__func__);
int linemax = getmaxline (*list);
int iterno = 0;
while (((*list)->lineno != num) && (iterno <= linemax)) {
    iterno++;
    list = &(*list)->prev;
}
printf ("passing list = &(*list)->next to tstpptr (%p)\n", list);
tstpptr (list);
// increment prev then next and check ptr values again
list = &(*list)->prev;
list = &(*list)->next;
printf ("passing list = &(*list)->next to tstpptr (%p)\n", list);
tstpptr (list);
}

void
tstpptr (rec **list) {
fprintf (stdout, "%s(): list      : %p\n", __func__, list);
fprintf (stdout, "%s(): &list     : %p\n", __func__, &list);
fprintf (stdout, "%s(): *list     : %p\n", __func__, *list);
fprintf (stdout, "%s(): &(*list)  : %p\n", __func__, &(*list));
fprintf (stdout, "%s(): &(**list) : %p\n\n", __func__, &(**list));
fprintf (stdout, "%s(): &(*list)->next : %p\n\n", __func__, &(*list)->next);
}
```

Comment: If going to next then to prev results in a different node, then that means the list structure is wrong. Can you show the snipped code that made the list structure in the first place?

Comment: sure, full source is here: http://www.3111skyline.com/dl/dev/prg/src/ll-double-cir-1.c.txt

May not all fit here:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see the problem - I don't think there is one. The important value is `*list`, which is the same in all cases. I think printing out list and &list etc is just clouding the issue.

In your forward iterator, `list` is pointing to the location of item #48's `next` variable.

In your backward iterator, `list` is pointing to the location of item #0's `prev` variable.

In both cases *list is pointing to the correct item #49.

Both functions would be much simpler if they just took a `rec *`, rather than a `rec **`, then it would be more obvious that taking the address of the `list` variable isn't what you want.

Comment: I think you are correct. The argument has to be rec ** to pass the caller's list by address, otherwise the delete will not work properly (see related thread). The problem actually occurs in delete when iterating in reverse, since list points to #0, when '(victim->next)->prev = victim->prev;' is called it just sets #0->prev = #0 which breaks the first node. I have a workaround, but it needs -- much refinement. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have uploaded a new copy of the source with a rough work-around to the reverse search/del problem. [ll-double-cir-2.c](http://www.3111skyline.com/dl/dev/prg/src/ll-double-cir-2.c.txt) I still do not fully understand why a reverse search leaves list pointing to the node before the node to delete while *list points to the correct node in all cases. The 'fix' simply sets a flag 1 if the list was searched in reverse and if so steps->prev; steps->next before deleting to insure list points to the right node - works, but is not elegant. Any other suggestions welcome.

Comment: I think the problem is that you are updating *list no matter which node you are deleting. The *list that is passed in only needs to change if you delete the first node in the list (so it can change textfile in main). I changed your delete by changing the parameter name to listParam, then copying its value into a local variable called list. Then only doing `*listParam = victim->next` if `*list == *listParam`. That way you are only ever updating the original passed in pointer, rather than what list has changed to. You then don't need your flag. Let me know if you want me to post the code.

Answer (score 0):

I took your code from the 3111skyline.com site, but it does not call the delete functions at all (or a lot of the other functions).  I added a function `validate_list()` which confirms that your list is constructed correctly.  And I created a loop to delete rows from your list, like this:

```
static void validate_list(rec *list)
{
    assert(list != 0);
    assert(list->next != 0);
    assert(list->prev != 0);
    rec *iter = list;
    do
    {
        assert(iter != 0);
        assert(iter->next != 0);
        assert(iter->prev != 0);
        assert(iter == iter->next->prev);
        assert(iter == iter->prev->next);
        printf("Node: %p (n = %p; p = %p) %2d [%s]\n",
               (void *)iter, (void *)iter->next,
               (void *)iter->prev, iter->lineno, iter->line);
        iter = iter->next;
    } while (iter != list);
}

int main(void)
{
    rec *textfile = fillrecord();
    validate_list(textfile);

    for (int i = 0; i < 49; i++)
    {
        delete_node(&textfile, (i * 13 + 31) % (50 - i));
        validate_list(textfile);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It all seems to work OK for me.  The next step would be to replace the deterministic (but not particularly obvious) sequence generated by the expression with random numbers to check that it works that way too, but the code seems clean to me.

Comment: thank you. The original source had the delete_line commented out for testing. I uploaded a recent version with my 'attempt' at the fix at [ll-double-cir-2.c](http://www.3111skyline.com/dl/dev/prg/src/ll-double-cir-2.c.txt) I still am a bit fuzzy on why 'list' pointed to different nodes when searching fwd/rev, but *list was pointing to the correct element. I'll read through your code and see if I can digest it. Thanks again.

Comment: just one question -- where did you come up with `(i * 13 + 31) % (50 - i)` ?? It is quite effective a generating a semi-random list of values in the loop range to test with (including duplicates, etc.), but not having run across it before -- where did it come from and what is the general rule for recreating something similar for different loop values? (Pick favorite pair of primes (first roughly 1/3 of range) within range, multiply first by counter add other prime to it, then mod by range -i ??

Comment: I've used similar expressions with the multiplier being mutually prime to the modulus (so GCD(multiplier, modulus) == 1), but I've normally needed a fixed modulus. When the multiplier is mutually prime to the modulus and you have a fixed modulus, you will generate all values 0..N-1 as the index increases.  This time, I needed a reducing modulus, so I chose two prime numbers not quite at random and used the (N-i) term to reduce it to a value in the current range.  I don't know that I ever found a source for it; it was just an 'obvious' way of generating non-obvious sequences of numbers.