# c linked-list, offsetof returns value that does not allow cast back to parent struct address

Tags: c, list, struct

**Related post:** [c circular double linked-list: rev traverse gives different list-pointer address for same node]
([c circular double linked-list: rev traverse gives different list-pointer address for same node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22703093/c-circular-double-linked-list-rev-traverse-gives-different-list-pointer-address))

Implementing a circular double linked-list with a generic list struct embedded in data struct [solution (3) in the **Related post above**] I have run into a problem where `offsetof(struct,member)` returns an incorrect offset. This prevents using the solution. I understand that reported offsets can be compiler dependent, but I need to know how to work with whatever result the compiler gives. The [**full source is this link**](http://www.3111skyline.com/dl/dev/prg/src/ll-offsetof.c.txt). The following shows the list implementation and the incorrect offsetof values received. I do not know why the offsefof value returned is not what is actually needed. For example, in the code below, offsetof (DataA,node) reports the offset (unsigned long) as 24, however a value of 80 is required?

```
typedef struct Node {
struct Node *prev, *next;
} Node;

typedef struct DataA {
int i;
char c;
double d;
char *a;
Node *node;
} DataA;

void
showlistA (Node *list, int manoff)
{
if (list ==  NULL) {
    fprintf (stdout,"%s(), The list is empty\n",__func__);
    return;
}

Node *iter = list;

do {
    int offset = (int)offsetof (DataA, node);
    DataA *offsetaddr = (DataA*)((unsigned long)iter - (unsigned long)offset);
    printf ("node: %p,  offsetof(DataA,node): %d,       result: %p,\n\t\t\t  \
            need offset: %d,  need result: %p\n\n",
        iter, offset, offsetaddr, manoff, (DataA*)((unsigned long)iter - manoff));

    iter = iter-> next;
} while (iter != list);
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

Node *list = NULL;
int manoffset = 80;

if (argc < 2)
    fprintf(stderr, "\nNote:  Usage: %s (int) (offsetof(DataA,node)) (default: 80)\n", argv[0]);

manoffset = (argv[1]) ? atoi (argv[1]) : 80;

printf ("\ncreate_node_Ann()\n");
create_node_Ann (&list, 1, 'A', 1000.101, "my dog has fleas");
create_node_Ann (&list, 2, 'B', 2000.101, "my cat has more");
create_node_Ann (&list, 3, 'C', 3000.101, "my snake has none");
create_node_Ann (&list, 4, 'D', 4000.101, "my hamster is fine");

printf ("\nNumber of nodes in 'list': %d\n\n", get_list_sz (list));

printf ("Node pointers (list validation):\n");
showlistptrs (list);
printf ("\n");
printf ("Offsets (reported/required):\n");
showlistA (list, manoffset);

/* Output is compiler dependent - reported results */
printf ("Offsets reported for each member of DataA:\n");
printf ("    offsets: i=%ld; c=%ld; d=%ld; a=%ld; node=%ld\n",
    (long) offsetof(struct DataA, i),
    (long) offsetof(struct DataA, c),
    (long) offsetof(struct DataA, d),
    (long) offsetof(struct DataA, a),
    (long) offsetof(struct DataA, node));
printf ("    sizeof(struct DataA)=%ld\n\n", (long) sizeof(struct DataA));

exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The output showing the offsetof values retured along with the list information is:

```
create_node_Ann()
1  DataA ndata  : 0x603010
   ndata-> node : 0x603060
2  DataA ndata  : 0x603080
   ndata-> node : 0x6030d0
3  DataA ndata  : 0x6030f0
   ndata-> node : 0x603140
4  DataA ndata  : 0x603160
   ndata-> node : 0x6031b0

Number of nodes in 'list': 4

Node pointers (list validation)
1  prev: 0x6031b0  cur: 0x603060  next: 0x6030d0
2  prev: 0x603060  cur: 0x6030d0  next: 0x603140
3  prev: 0x6030d0  cur: 0x603140  next: 0x6031b0
4  prev: 0x603140  cur: 0x6031b0  next: 0x603060

Offsets (reported/required):
node: 0x603060,  offsetof(DataA,node): 24,       result: 0x603048,
                          need offset: 80,  need result: 0x603010

node: 0x6030d0,  offsetof(DataA,node): 24,       result: 0x6030b8,
                          need offset: 80,  need result: 0x603080

node: 0x603140,  offsetof(DataA,node): 24,       result: 0x603128,
                          need offset: 80,  need result: 0x6030f0

node: 0x6031b0,  offsetof(DataA,node): 24,       result: 0x603198,
                          need offset: 80,  need result: 0x603160

Offsets reported for each member of DataA:
offsets: i=0; c=4; d=8; a=16; node=24
sizeof(struct DataA)=32
```

I do not understand why the offsetof value is so different that what is required. Why is `DataA *p = (DataA*)((uintptr_t)iter - offsetof(DataA, node));` returning `24` instead of `80`? The full program takes a single argument (offset) and applies that as a manual offset to allow the correct cast between the list node and DataA struct addresses to be entered. (that's how I tested what was actually needed, along with my calculator). How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing it this way?  Seems very awkward.

Comment: 4+4+8+4+4 = 24 .  Why would you think it is 80?

Comment: I can't find "Solution 3", but mostly when you implement "intrusive" linked lists you store a struct, not a pointer, inside the data.

Comment: @Jim: I think it is 4 + 4 + 8 + 8, since it's offsetof(node), not sizeof(DataA). But it's all speculation, innit?

Comment: Why 80? Look at node 1: the embedded list address is `ndata-> node : 0x603060`, the DataA struct address is `DataA ndata  : 0x603010`. Subtracting `0x603060 - 0x603010 = 80 bytes`. Not to mention that is the only way to get data back out of the list. Look at the printf statement added to `showlistA` [**in this source**](http://www.3111skyline.com/dl/dev/prg/src/ll-offsetof.c.txt)

Comment: I apologize. The correct [**Related Post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22798715/c-linked-list-is-it-possible-to-create-a-payload-independent-iterator-function). It is **Solution 3** in the answer to this post I was working to implement. Also, regarding molbdnilo's response regarding embedding the pointer or struct Node, it looks like that may be what is happening. member `node` appears to exist in memory somewhere after `struct DataA` ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the definition of DataA with node defined as a pointer instead of a structure as pointed out by @molbdnilo. The correct definition of struct DataA is:

```
typedef struct DataA {
    int i;
    char c;
    double d;
    char *a;
    Node node;
} DataA;
```

After redefining node as a struct instead of a pointer to a struct, the offsetof values are correct. Thanks to all for your help.